# Retrieve specific value from JSON in C#

Tags: c#, json, parsing

I need to get values from the JSON below, for example how to index Id in Info?

The whole JSON consists of many matches, this just one with Id `5aa891cd1e1422452e8b4567`, and this is a structure of one match.

I try with:

```
var jsonDATA = JObject.Parse(data);

foreach (var e in jsonDATA["events"]) {
    //in this step, the result is JSON below
    var id = e["info"]["id"];` // error: cannot access child value on newtonsoft json linq jproperty
}
```

Any ideas?

```
{"5aa891cd1e1422452e8b4567": {
      "info": {
        "id": "5aa891cd1e1422452e8b4567",
        "event_id": "58911142245284567",
        "name": "Santos Laguna vs Queretaro",
        "sport": "Soccer",
        "league": "Mexico Cup",
        "period": "Finished",
        "score": "1:0",
        "status": "Live",
        "start_time": "2018.03.14 03:06:53",
        "state": 1017,
        "state_name": "Fulltime",
        "minute": 90,
        "safe": false,
        "safe2": false,
        "blocked": false,
        "stop": false
      },
      "stats": {
        "home": {
          "name": "Santos Laguna",
          "color": "",
          "position": "",
          "on_target": "",
          "off_target": "",
          "attacks": "",
          "dangerous_attacks": "",
          "possession": "",
          "goals": 1,
          "corners": 5,
          "yellowcards": 1,
          "redcards": 0,
          "throwins": 0,
          "freekicks": 0,
          "goalkicks": 0,
          "penalties": 0,
          "substitutions": 3,
          "ht_result": 1
        },
        "away": {
          "name": "Queretaro",
          "color": "",
          "position": "",
          "on_target": "",
          "off_target": "",
          "attacks": "",
          "dangerous_attacks": "",
          "possession": "",
          "goals": 0,
          "corners": 8,
          "yellowcards": 3,
          "redcards": 1,
          "throwins": 0,
          "freekicks": 0,
          "goalkicks": 0,
          "penalties": 0,
          "substitutions": 3,
          "ht_result": 0
        }
      },
      "odds": []
    }}
```

Comment: Your json data do not represent, what your javascript expect - are you showing the right javascript/json data?

Comment: `jsonDATA["events"]` should be `jsonDATA["5aa891cd1e1422452e8b4567"]`, but it is not an array

Comment: @karlo Can you check on which child property this throws the error; when getting "info" or "id" ?

Comment: well then he must do this; `e["5aa891cd1e1422452e8b4567"]["info"]["id"]` for that element? Is the first element a `Guid` on each element in the array?

Comment: @FrankNielsen yes the first element is Guid, it is match ID, 
I have to go looping over the matches and get info and other statistical data about a match,
I also try
 var id = e["5aa891cd1e1422452e8b4567"]["Info"]["id"];, but I still have error: Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty.'

Comment: @AbdullahDibas I do not have any info on which property trows error, just Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty.

Also I validate JSON online, strucutre JSON ist okay

Answer (score 2):

You can use anonymous type [deserialization](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeAnonymousType.htm) for your data like this. Hope it works.

```
//using Newtonsoft.Json;
var jsonData = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(
    data,
    new 
    {
      events = new[]
      {
        new
        { 
          Id = new { info = "", stats = "", away = "", odds = "" }
        }
      }
  );            

foreach(var item in jsonData.events)
{
    var id=item.info.id; // getting id present in info
}
```

Comment: I can get value  of name with this: 
string name1 = MATCHES["events"]["5aa891cd1e1422452e8b4567"]["info"]["id"].ToString();


but 5aab5b9a1d1422b7488b4567 is guid which changes all time, JSON structure is determined except guid, 

How to handle or map guid in C# class?

Comment: `foreach` loop will give answer to ur commented question. `item`_in foreach_ always gives your guid @karlo

Comment: I can go with foreach loop over first level of JSON
like: var match = (from x in MATCHES["events"] select x).ToList() 

and it is working- the result is JSON above in code post,  but to loop over Info members, or Stats ??
All time I have error: Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty

foreach(JProperty x in MATCHES.SelectToken("events"))
                    {
            foreach (JProperty y in x.SelectToken("info"))
                            {
                            }
                        }